# How to apply one hot encoding on unseen future data in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working with Titanic data as a sample set and I have come across a use case where I want to do one hot encoding during training phase and then apply my model. After this is done, I am planning to store the model so that I can load the model back and `score` the unseen dataset. The plan is have 2 `.py` files. One is `train.py` that will load the data, do feature engineering, apply logistic model and then `save` the model to disk. Second file is `score.py`. In `score.py` , I want to first take an entire unseen dataset, load the model from disk and then score that data to generate predictions. The problem is that in `score.py` I will have to transform the raw unseen data to `one-hot encoded` columns before generating predictions.

Here is some code for `train.py`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


data_set = data[['Pclass','Sex','Age','Fare','SibSp','Cabin']]
one_hot_encoded_training_predictors = pd.get_dummies(data_set)
one_hot_encoded_training_predictors.head()
X = one_hot_encoded_training_predictors
y = data['Survived']

#Train Test split---75 25 ratio
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
logreg = LogisticRegression() 
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)


##predicting test accuracy
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test) #predicting the values

# Save model code here

logreg.save(..)
```

My `score.py` would look like

```
import statements
unseen_data = pd.read_csv(..) # this is raw unseen data

model.load(..)
model.predict(unseen_data)
```

Now imagine I have an unseen set which is never seen by the model. I can load the trained model using `logreg.load(..)` but the problem I am facing is, how do I first perform the one hot encoding on my raw unseen features? Can I also `save` the one hot encoding objects to be re-used on unseen set? I am new to Machine Learning and I might be missing something very simple but that is the issue I need to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you you use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), you can handle unknown categories by setting up **handle_unknown** parameter to **"ignore"**. When this parameter is set to ‘ignore’ and an unknown category is encountered during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros. In the inverse transform, an unknown category will be denoted as None.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think part of the problem is how to perform that oneHotEncoding on an entire `unseen dataset`. Imagine there are 2 files - `train.py` which saves the logit model and then there is `score.py`. My question is more towards converting unseen data to features using that `score.py` and then loading the saved model so that I can score on `unseen dataset`.

Comment: I have edited my question for more clearer understanding